# Teradata PDE state: DOWN/HARDSTOP

Tags: teradata

I have ran /etc/init.d/tpa start but it says

`Teradata Database Initiator service failed with 4 exit code`

I have ran /var/log/messages but it says

`bash: /var/log/messages: Permission denied`

I need some help to get the database running. Thanks!

Comment: You don't "run" /var/log/messages, it's a text log file. Recent messages (tail of the file) may provide more insight as to the failure reason.   Is this Teradata / Vantage Express VMware?

Comment: Yes it is @Fred. Do you have a workaround?

Comment: Hard to say without a failure reason. Maybe try the `/etc/init.d/tpa start` again and then `tail -n 500 /var/log/messages |grep Teradata |grep -v INFO`

Comment: I just ran 
```/etc/init.d/tpa start``` 
and it started successfully. Then I ran 
```pdestate -a``` 
and PDE state is now RUN/STARTED.

Thank you @Fred for your help.

I don't know why Teradata fails to start sometimes. Maybe it was because I powered off the VM instead of saving state. All it took to literally get it working was to sleep over it and try the tpa start command again. Funny system.

Comment: If you are going to power off the VM, best practice is to stop the database with `tpareset -x "some comment"` first and wait for pdestate to be DOWN/HARDSTOP. Then you should be able to shut down or reboot the VM without an issue.

Comment: That's noted, thanks a mill!

Comment: Hi @Fred, do you know how I can access the advanced sql engine? Do I need to install it? As I intend to use it for learning purposes, can I get it for free?

Comment: Advanced SQL Engine is just a prior marketing name for the database. Vantage Express is the free version. Teradata does offer other products and ecosystem components outside the database itself, which are not available with Vantage Express. The next step up would be one of the "Developer Edition" distributions, which require dedicated virtual machines (e.g. vSphere or public cloud). Those do not have license fees, but public cloud will incur cloud provider charges.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly do I need to install? Cos when I try to use functions like ScaleMap, Antiselect_MLE etc. in Vantage Express, I get errors.

Comment: Those functions are only available on legacy systems that include "MLE nodes" and were never available on Vantage Express. See https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise/Teradata-Package-for-Python-Function-Reference-17.20/teradataml-ML-Engine-Analytic-Functions-legacy